# Groovy - idiomatic way of coding The Last Weekday - First of Month

Tags: datetime, groovy, calendar, idioms

What is the Groovy idiomatic way of asking for the last past weekday (ex. Monday)?
(or current week, the first day of the week)?

Also is there something similar for asking for the current month, the first of month?

Comment: Check out the [Groovy -JN0454-Dates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates)

Comment: Even though it's not Groovy-specific [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) might be very helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Date firstDayInWeek(Date day) {
    day.clearTime()
    return day - day.calendarDate.dayOfWeek
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. +1 Few questions how do I need to tweak it to get Monday as the first day of the week? I get two different Saturdays when comparing new Date(2011,7,6) and new Date(2011,7,5)

Comment: Are you modifying the method parameter? A nasty side effect.

Comment: Yes, I did change the parameter - which was ok in my special case but is certainly not a good idea in general. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: dayOfWeek returns 1 to 7, with 1 being Sunday. Therefore, our week starts at Saturday

Answer (score 3):

A year ago, I wrote a [simple DSL for calculating dates](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/27001), this allows you to do:

```
def mondayInJuly = new DateDSL().with {
  first.monday.in.july( 2011 )
}
```

which sets `mondayInJuly` to be a Date object representing

```
Mon Jul 04 00:00:00 UTC 2011
```

I need to update the script to allow you to use Groovy 1.8's more lenient parser

Comment: that's the grooviest way, sweet!

Answer (score 1):

As you mention `DateTime` in tags, I suggest JodaTime is OK. So, we do:

```
def lastMonday = 
  new DateTime().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY).minusWeeks(1)
def firstThisMoth = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(1)
```